# WPF Dependency Property for Custom Control

Tags: c#, wpf, custom-controls, dependency-properties

I'm a bit in a mess with how to set a Dependency Property for Custom Control.

I created Custom Control, so it derives from Control class.

```
public class CustControl : Control 
    {
      static CustControl()
       {
         DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(CustControl), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(CustControl)));       
       }        
    }
```

In order to set Dependency Property I have to register it inside a class which must be derived from DependencyObject. So it should be another class:

```
class CustClass : DependencyObject
{
    public readonly static DependencyProperty MyFirstProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("MyFirst", typeof(string), typeof(CustControl), new PropertyMetadata(""));

    public string MyFirst
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(MyFirstProperty); }
        set { SetValue(MyFirstProperty, value); }
    }
}
```

How now I could set MyFirst property as dependency property for CustControl?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> In order to set Dependency Property I have to register it inside a class which must be derived from DependencyObject. So it should be another class:

No, it shouldn't. `Control` already derives from `DependencyObject`. Since inheritance is [transitive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transitive_relation), this makes `CustControl` a subtype of `DependencyObject` as well. Just put it all into `CustControl`:

```
public class CustControl : Control 
{
      static CustControl()
      {
          DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(CustControl), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(CustControl)));       
      }        

    public readonly static DependencyProperty MyFirstProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("MyFirst", typeof(string), typeof(CustControl), new PropertyMetadata(""));

    public string MyFirst
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(MyFirstProperty); }
        set { SetValue(MyFirstProperty, value); }
    }
}
```